# RTSP player for Android

Tags: proxy, rtsp

I'm curios if there is any RTSP Player for android which allows specify port for I guess A/V communication.
My situation:
I want to stream over my RTSP Proxy, but there is a restrictive company FW, but for our purposes there are few port in DMZ, but I couldn't find any android RTSP player which allows specify these ports.
We can do that on Symbian, because there is Real Player, which allows it.
Any hints or workarounds?

Comment: Shouldn't the port be specified by the stream, not the client?

Comment: @Matthew Read: I need to go over proxy, which is in DMZ, but only on few specific ports, which can be used for A/V communication, otherwise interleaved mode is requested (I can live also with this solution, but i need to set up proxy for RTSP)

Answer (score 2):

Default **video player** on Android does support RTSP. You can specify the port in the url (`<server>:<port>`)

[image]

Comment: For programmers, [VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) does support rtsp urls

Comment: Well, but do not support setting up proxy server, respectively specific ports which shall be used.

Answer (score 0):

[Real player has a beta version for Android phones](http://www.real.com/realplayer/android), so maybe it will be the one you are looking for.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately Real player for Android does not have this feature.